# Change UIViewController background color with custom UIToolbar XIB Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, toolbar

I'm new to swift, I would like to change my UIViewController background color from the custom UIToolbar that I already created at XIB. I also already add the custom toolbar to my keyboard. ***How can i do that?***

In my toolbar, I have a button that indicates the color that the user can set to the background color of UIViewController.

**My Custom Toolbar**

[image: My Custom Toolbar]

***Class for custom toolbar, ColorToolbar.swift***

```
import UIKit

class ColorToolbar: UIToolbar {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var purpleButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var blueButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var greenButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var yellowButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var redButton: UIBarButtonItem!

   var makeNotesVC = MakeNotesVC()
  
    var selectedColor : UIColor = UIColor.clear

    
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupButtonColor()
    }
    
    @IBAction func colorButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        guard let color = sender.tintColor else {return}
        selectedColor = color
        print(selectedColor)
       makeNotesVC.view.backgroundColor = selectedColor
    }
    @objc func changeBgColor(){
        makeNotesVC.view.backgroundColor = selectedColor
    }
    private func setupButtonColor(){
        purpleButton.tintColor = Constants.TintColorButton.purple
        blueButton.tintColor = Constants.TintColorButton.blue
        greenButton.tintColor = Constants.TintColorButton.green
        yellowButton.tintColor = Constants.TintColorButton.yellow
        redButton.tintColor = Constants.TintColorButton.red
    }
}
```

***Class for UIViewController that i want to change background color, MakeNotesVC.swift***

```
import UIKit

class MakeNotesVC: UIViewController {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    @IBOutlet weak var titleTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var notesText: UITextView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addColorbutton()
    }
    
    @IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let newNote = Note(context: context)
        newNote.title = titleTextfield.text
        newNote.text = notesText.text
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
    func addColorbutton(){
        // TODO : Add Color Options Toolbar
    
        //Register custom toolbar
        let toolbar = UINib(nibName: "Toolbar", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! ColorToolbar
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        //Add toolbar to keyboard
        titleTextfield.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        notesText.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    }
  
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `var makeNotesVC = MakeNotesVC()` is wrong. That is not your view controller! Please, please read and think about: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add protocol at your custom tool bar

```
protocol BackgroundColorControlDelegate: AnyObject {
    func changeBackgroundColor(sender:Any, color: UIColor)
}

import UIKit

class ColorToolbar: UIToolbar {

    @IBOutlet weak var purpleButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var blueButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var greenButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var yellowButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var redButton: UIBarButtonItem!

   var makeNotesVC = MakeNotesVC()
   var selectedColor : UIColor = UIColor.clear
   weak var delegate: BackgroundColorControlDelegate?


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupButtonColor()
    }

    @IBAction func colorButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        guard let color = sender.tintColor else {return}
        selectedColor = color
        print(selectedColor)
        delegate?.changeBackgroundColor(sender: self, color: color)
    }
    @objc func changeBgColor(){
        makeNotesVC.view.backgroundColor = selectedColor
    }
    private func setupButtonColor(){
        purpleButton.tintColor = Constants.TintColorButton.purple
        blueButton.tintColor = Constants.TintColorButton.blue
        greenButton.tintColor = Constants.TintColorButton.green
        yellowButton.tintColor = Constants.TintColorButton.yellow
        redButton.tintColor = Constants.TintColorButton.red
    }
}
```

call delegate from MakeNotesVC

```
import UIKit

class MakeNotesVC: UIViewController {

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
@IBOutlet weak var titleTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var notesText: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addColorbutton()
}

@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let newNote = Note(context: context)
    newNote.title = titleTextfield.text
    newNote.text = notesText.text
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}

func addColorbutton(){
    // TODO : Add Color Options Toolbar

    //Register custom toolbar
    let toolbar = UINib(nibName: "Toolbar", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! ColorToolbar
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    toolbar.delegate = self
    //Add toolbar to keyboard
    titleTextfield.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    notesText.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
}

}

extension MakeNotesVC: BackgroundColorControlDelegate  {
    func changeBackgroundColor(sender:Any, color: UIColor) {
        view.backgroundColor = color
    }
}
```

Comment: regarding your answers, there's some issue with the delegate, it says **Property 'delegate' with type 'BackgroundColorControlDelegate?' cannot override a property with type 'UIToolbarDelegate?'**

Comment: try change variable delegate to other name